# Why are commands used in (pre|post)inst scripts not listed in dependencies?

Tags: package-management, deb

I constantly get error messages, that `xargs` or some other admittedly basic command is missing, when trying to install `.deb` files with `dpkg` in a minimal linux environment.

`xargs` is part of the `findutils` package, which has the priority `required`. Does that mean, that packages of this priority are never in the dependencies (which `findutils` is in some packages) because the developers/maintainers can assume it is available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packages have to specify all their dependencies, unless the package depended on is "Essential".

https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#s-dependencies

> Packages are not required to declare any dependencies they have on other packages which are marked Essential (see below), and should not do so unless they depend on a particular version of that package.[10]

And findutils is essential, at least on my system.

```
$ apt-cache show findutils
Package: findutils
Essential: yes
Priority: required
```

Comment: If you're doing this inside a chroot, look into [debootstrap](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap)

Comment: Ah. Didn't see the `Essential` attribute. I was so focused on `Priority`. debootstrap in not an option for me, but thanks for mentioning it.